# USB Bootable Linux

Tags: installation, boot, usb

I have created the USB bootable linux on an flash drive. But when I start it up it keeps asking me to install Linux. Would installing linux install it on my desktop. Is there a way to run linux off of the flash drive so that it won't affect my current operating system?

Thanks!

Comment: Which Ubuntu release are you using, and how did you create the USB?

Answer (score 0):

In all likelihood you have created an install USB, not a bootable system. To create a bootable Ubuntu flash drive follow [this tutorial](http://blog.hostonnet.com/how-to-create-bootable-live-usb-ubuntu-with-unetbootin).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have not created the live usb properly. You need to create the live USB again.

I belive you are using Ubuntu 12.04 run the following commands in terminal to install `unetbootin`

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gezakovacs/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```

After installing `unetbootin`

This is how the GUI will look like

[image: unetbootin]

Or if you are using Windows I suggest you use USB installer provided at www.pendrivelinux.com

For further instructions

[Universal USB installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)